# Turn this sub into a function so that I could update all the other charts on Sheet2 without having to repeat the code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub updateChart1()

   Dim month
   Dim year
   Dim stringToFind
   Dim newRange
   Dim foundString
   Dim newRange1
   Dim newrange2

   'Assign a value to the month and the year
   month = VBA.DateTime.month(Date)
   year = VBA.DateTime.year(Date)

   'Make the search for string equal to the month + year variables
   stringToFind = month & "/" & year

   'Declare a range where you will look for the month and year
   Set newRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:Z16")

   'Search for the month and year
   Set foundString = newRange.Find(stringToFind)

   'Once the correct date has been found, resize the range to be the new data source
   Set newRange1 = foundString.Offset(0, -12)

   Set newrange2 = newRange1.Resize(2, 12)


   'Update the chart with the new data source
   Worksheets("Sheet2").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=newrange2

End Sub
```

I am sure there must be a better way than repeating this code, but am not sure how to turn it into a repeatable function given that newRange will be different for each chart - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just pass newRange and worksheet reference as argument.

```
Private Sub updateChart1(newRange As Range)

'I decided that only Range in argument list is enough. You may refer to the worksheet by newRange.Parent. 

Dim month
Dim year
Dim stringToFind
Dim foundString
Dim newRange1
Dim newrange2
```

remove the line;

```
Set newRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C16:Z16")
```

You then can use this sub in your code, letting it do the job for any sheet and range you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. How exactly do I reference the worksheet and range that newRange is on, I can't get the correct syntax? Also, in the new sub I would also then need to tell it which chart to update?

Comment: updateChart1 worksheets("sheet1").Range("C16:Z16") and see my Edit.

Comment: But then if I call updatechart1 in another sub, how do I get it to update a different chart, at the sub is still looking at Chart1? Thanks

Comment: you may either pass chart reference as argument or ask the sub look for himself. But it looks as another question.